# making a list with an interval based of a another list symmetrically

Tags: python, math

I'm sure the way I phrased the question is wrong but I'm at a loss here... I need to find out how to find out which numbers in a list are in the interval of a number I give it. i added a picture to help explain.

[image]

let's say I have 12 items across and want to add something to those items in an interval of 2 (or whatever number I give it). you can see that doing something that is 11 wide is easy but when you try and do it with an even number I have to skip the 2 in the middle to keep them symmetrical. how would I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the operation of the list twice. Once forward and once in reverse. Then you keep only the first half from each list and concatenate them back together.

````py
def add_symetric(lst, num, interval):
    length = len(lst)
    half_length = length // 2
    
    from_start = [val + num if ind % interval == 0 else val for ind, val in enumerate(lst)]
    from_end = list(reversed([val + num if ind % interval == 0 else val for ind, val in enumerate(reversed(lst))]))
    
    adjustment = length % 2
    return from_start[0:half_length+adjustment] + from_end[-half_length:]


even_list = range(22)
odd_list = range(21)

print(list(even_list))
print(add_symetric(even_list, 2, 2))
print()

print(list(odd_list))
print(add_symetric(odd_list, 2, 2))
print()```
````